# How can I convert dd hh:mm format into hours?

Tags: excel-formula

I'm a complete novice at excel so I'm hoping there is a simple solution I just don't understand, but I'm pulling data from a generated report that contains the average turn around time of a lab test in the format d hh:mm (eg. 1 14:20). Am I correct in custom formatting these cells as d hh:mm, and if so is there a way to convert this into hours so I can average the TAT for all tests in that group?

Comment: `=HOUR(A1)`????

Comment: Is there a specific cell format to use when the time displayed is d hh:mm? I've tried everything that makes sense to me, but still get a value error when trying to convert.

Comment: Then most likely your date/time is a string and not a true date/time.  It will need to be converted, which is different than the format.  Format only works on numbers not text strings.

Comment: Nailed it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1** use:

```
=A1 * 24
```

[image]

This is a pretty standard way to convert time to hours.

Comment: What format does A1 need to be in? I'm getting a value error with the current format, I'm assuming because there's no leading zero?

Comment: @Spearsy23  If the formula yields value error then the original data is probably **Text** rather than **Numeric**